# Is there a way to use Machine Learning classify discrete and infinite scale data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, discrete-mathematics, supervised-learning

The data like that:

```
x    y
7773 0
9805 4
7145 0
7645 1
2529 1
4814 2
6027 2
7499 2
3367 1
8861 5
9776 2
8009 5
3844 2
1218 2
1120 1
4553 0
3017 1
2582 2
1691 2
5342 0
...
```

The real function f(x) is: (Return the circle count of a decimal integer)

```
#         0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
_f_map = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1]

def f(x):
    x = int(x)
    assert x >= 0
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    r = 0
    while x:
        r += _f_map[x % 10]
        x /= 10
    return r
```

The training data and test data can be produced by random:

```
data = []
target = []
for i in xrange(3000):
    x = random.randint(0, 999999) #hardcode a scale
    data.append([x])
    target.append(f(x))
```

The real function is discrete and infinite scale.

Is there a way or a model can classify this data?

I tried SVM(Support Vector Machine), and acquired a 20% accuracy rate.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typical use case of sequential models. You can easily learn LSTM/ other recurrent neural network to do so by considering your numbers as sequences of integers feeded to the network. At this point it just has to learn sum operation and a simple mapping(your f_map).